# How to merge two similar but not entirely the same tables into one?

Tags: tables, info-visualisation, information-architecture

I have 2 tables that display orders to be processed. Top one is through **Delivery**, while the bottom one is through **Self-Collection**.

[image]

I don't want to keep them into 2 separate tables because all of them deal with orders and it's easier to search just one table for a particular order than have to search in 2 different locations.

But then the other columns would be redundant to the other (Self-Collection).

What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: Would there be any problem showing N/A in the Delivery status field for the SelCollection items?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is display only one table at a time
You can try something like this[image]
which has **radio buttons** 
or you can also use **dropdown** or **tab** structure also instead of **radio button**

Comment: This one I understand, but my problem is when I display both Delivery and Self-Collection at the same time, how do I structure the table? This example still makes them into separate tables.

Comment: a good UX practice is not displaying any irrelevant data to user. so think of displaying only one table at a time.

Comment: But if there's a search bar on top and I searched for let's say "Name" Winnie Goh, which both can have "Self-Collect" or "Delivery".. how should it show?

Comment: if it has both then it shall show something on default and the user must be given option to switch the view if he needs.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add an additional column stating the type? (Delivery/Self-Collection) Redundant columns are fine, and is expected for varied data within a table. However I don't think having them in the same table is not a good idea due to the actions that are required to be executed.

Having the 'Marked as assigned' and 'Marked for collection' buttons so visually similar is confusing, especially when they are going to be on the same column. If you insist on having the tables merged, consider having two buttons at the same time, but with the unavailable option disabled.

I work in a logistics company with both operational and customer-facing touchpoints, and as with all user-centric design, you really need user research to know which patterns your users are most comfortable with.